# Any real world implementation using message recovery?

Tags: rsa, implementation, message-recovery

During my master thesis I came across RSA-PSS-R which is in my opinion a quite elegant way of saving bandwidth and space using digital signature.
But I didn't find any information about any real world implementation out there. I have the feeling that it's exactly like the Schnorr Signature scheme. Everybody says that it is very efficient, but no one actually uses it.

Maybe I didn't dig deep enough but is there anyone out there actually using message recovery AT ALL in any real world implementation?

Thank you for your feedback

Comment: My guess is that since in real world one uses the "hash then sign" paradigm (i.e., hash a message and sign the hash value) a signature scheme with message recovery does not really give an added value, since you can only recover the hash value (which, due to the one-wayness of the hash function will not let you recover the message itself).

Comment: @DrLecter Even when using a hash as part of the signature one could put the (beginning of the) message into the remaining space.

Comment: @CodesInChaos yes thats true. Actually I did not think of very small message spaces :/ Clearly, in authentication protocols and resource constraint environments that feature could actually make sense. Didn't think of that either :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A signature scheme with message recovery is standardized as ISO/IEC 9796-2 ([link to preview](http://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_isoiec9796-2%7Bed3.0%7Den.pdf)). Scheme 1 in this standard is commonly used in the Smart Card industry, despite its [known weaknesses](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/203) in a chosen-message setup.

Example real-life uses include the [EMV banking application](http://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=223) (the free documents linked there include a description of an industry-standard subset of ISO/IEC 9796-2 Scheme 1; there is support for this subset in [JavaCard 2.2.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javacard/specs-138637.html) and up); and the certificates in the [European Digital Tachograph](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CONSLEG:1985R3821:20121001:EN:PDF) system (head to Annex 1B, appendix 11).

Update: As kindly [pointed by Maarten Bodewes](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11746/555#comment24729_11748), that is also used in [ICAO e-passport specifications](http://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/9303_p3_v2_cons_en.pdf), appendix 4.

Comment: Not to mention ICAO specifications for passports which use it in the Active Authentication protocol - although for that it is only used within a challenge response protocol (the challenge is recovered). Tacho also uses it for certificates, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I will have a look at it. Thx for the advice

Answer (score 2):

Some implementations of RSA PKCS#1v1.5 use message recovery to find out which hash function was applied.

PKCS#11 API defines the C_SignRecover and C_VerifyRecover and allow them to be used with the most RSA mechanisms. Long story short: this means that there is very widely available API which allows the functionality. Thus, it is likely that quite a few pieces of software use it in practice.